# Testing On Page Load Function

Tags: jquery

How do make sure that my $(document).ready( function() { ...  } ) block executes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave this up to jQuery. They test their code thoroughly. If you just want to *know* if it executed, simply throw an `alert` or something in there.

Comment: I did. And nothing happened. What are some ways to make sure that it will execute then. Firebug doesn't seem to reveal any errors.

Comment: @syker: Try restarting Firefox. I've had instances in which the Firefox Javascript engine did not produce consistent results until I restarted it.

Comment: Making sure it will execute is jQuery's job, once it's told to.  If it doesn't execute, then it's not being set up -- that is, the code that'd set it up is not being executed.  It'd be hard to help without seeing the code.

Comment: It's a lot of code but basically my one file includes another PHP file that also has a $(document).ready( function() { ... } ) block. I'm seeing an example of my friend's code where his two $(document).ready( function() { ... } ) blocks execute just fine. Is there a Javascript checker I can download for Firefox?

Comment: Resolved my problem. I had too many unnecessary messages being logged to Firebug. Firebug did indeed log the error that I was experiencing.